# Maintain aspect ratio of circles when window re-sizes

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, flexbox

I have circles lined up using flexbox and they look decent on small screen width:

[image]

but as soon as I widen the width of my screen, they look really stretched. But I need them to be round from every prospect.

[image]

I'm not sure maybe there is a way that fixes their displaying on different screen sizes. Maybe I could have used some media queries. How to handle this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qsanw7oL/)

**HTML**

```
 <div class="dashboard-grey-menu">
   <div class="flex row no-padding">
     <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
     <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
     <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
     <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.dashboard-grey-menu {
    height: 30vh;
    background-color: #959595;
  }

  .circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 25vh;
    background-color: #B7B7B7;
    margin: auto;
  }

.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the `width` and `height` of your circle to the same value:

```css
.dashboard-grey-menu {
  height: 30vh;
  background-color: #959595;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: #B7B7B7;
  margin: 20px;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ion-content has-header="false">
  <div class="dashboard-grey-menu">
    <div class="flex row no-padding">
      <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
      <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
      <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
      <div class="col"><div class="circle"></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: replace `margin:auto` with `margin:20px` or any other value to get some space. ... or `justify-content: space-between;` on `.flex` and a `padding` to `.dashboard-grey-menu`.

Comment: you can define a `max-height` **and** `max-width` < the `height` of `.flex` (actually 30vh): https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/0ascecqs/1/